# No module named pywebhdfs.web hdfs

Tags: webhdfs

I’ve installed pywebhdfs on 5 nodes and verified each by

python
help ('pywebhdfs')

Help on package pywebhdfs:

NAME
    pywebhdfs

FILE
    /../pywebhdfs/**init**.py

Getting "No module named pywebhdfs.web hdfs"

Appreciate and help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install something else as well:

pip install WebHDFS